# Getting 403 authorisation error when try to release Azure container lease

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

**Code below fixed as per the helping comments. Now allows me to release the lease on a container, assuming you know the lease id.**

I've been using Azure as an archive backup for a large number of files. I don't think it makes a huge amount of difference to day-to-day usage, but I accidentally hit the 'acquire lease' option on my container in the portal. The only two options in the portal are acquire and break, there isn't a 'release' option.

I'm trying to get back in to Python, and saw this as a possibility to practice by trying to interact with Azure APIs.

[This link][1] forms 95% of the code (retrieving the properties). I get a successful response when configured with my credentials (a 202).

I've then attempted to modify the code to release the lease:

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = 'storageaccountname'
storage_account_key = 'storateaccountkey'
lease_id = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
container_name = 'containername'
api_version = '2019-07-07'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'PUT',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-lease-action:release' + '\nx-ms-lease-id:' + lease_id + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/' + container_name + '\ncomp:lease\nrestype:container'
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])


print (string_to_sign)

signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.HMAC(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()
print (signed_string)

headers = {
    'x-ms-date': request_time,
    'x-ms-lease-action': 'release',
    'x-ms-lease-id': lease_id,
    'x-ms-version': api_version,
    'Authorization': ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
}

url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + container_name + '?comp=lease&restype=container')

r = requests.put(url, headers = headers)

print (r)
print(r.content)
```

I got the lease ID by going in to the portal, breaking the lease and then acquiring a new one.

I get a 403 error, with the following information (obfuscated for obvious reasons):

```
<Response [403]>
b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX\nTime:2020-04-15T21:59:08.6983006Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request \'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=\' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: \'PUT\n\n\n53\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Thu, 16 Apr 2020 21:46:56 GMT\nx-ms-lease-action:release\nx-ms-lease-id:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX\nx-ms-version:2019-07-07\n/storageaccountname/containername\ncomp:lease\nrestype:container\'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>'
```

How can I release a lease? It must be something I'm doing in the headers, but I can't figure out where.

UPDATE (Based on latest code provided in replies). Get this error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Azure_release_lease_2.py", line 49, in <module>
    signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.HMAC(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256).digest())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\hmac.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.update(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\hmac.py", line 96, in update
    self.inner.update(msg)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code because of which you're getting this error.

First, you didn't include `x-ms-lease-id` and `x-ms-lease-action` in your `CanonicalizedHeaders`.

From the documentation [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#constructing-the-canonicalized-headers-string):

> Retrieve all headers for the resource that begin with x-ms-, including
>   the x-ms-date header.

```
'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-lease-action:acquire' + '\nnx-ms-lease-id:' + theleaseidfromazureportal + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
```

Next, there's an issue with `CanonicalizedResource`. Currently it is missing container name and has incorrect values for `comp` and `restype` query parameters.

```
'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/' + container_name + '/\ncomp:lease\nrestype:container'
```

Lastly your URL should be:

```
url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + container_name + '?comp=lease&restype=container')
```

Currently it is missing container name.

Please refer to lease container REST API documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-container.

Furthermore, you don't really have to consumer REST API, there's a Python SDK for Azure Storage which is a wrapper over this REST API. You can find more information about the SDK here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage.

---

**UPDATE**

Found one issue in your updated code. In your `string_to_sign`, you're including `Content-Type` as `application/xml` however the same is not included in your request headers. This is causing your signatures to mismatch. Either add `Content-Type` request header in your `headers` definition or use an empty string in your `string_to_sign`. That should take care of the problem. Considering `Release Lease` request doesn't have a request body, I would recommend the latter.

**UPDATE 2**

There were a few other issues with your code. Please use the code below, it should work:

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

storage_account_name = 'storageaccountname'
storage_account_key = 'storateaccountkey'
lease_id = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
container_name = 'containername'
api_version = '2019-07-07'
request_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

string_params = {
    'verb': 'PUT',
    'Content-Encoding': '',
    'Content-Language': '',
    'Content-Length': '',
    'Content-MD5': '',
    'Content-Type': '',
    'Date': '',
    'If-Modified-Since': '',
    'If-Match': '',
    'If-None-Match': '',
    'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
    'Range': '',
    'CanonicalizedHeaders': 'x-ms-date:' + request_time + '\nx-ms-lease-action:release' + '\nx-ms-lease-id:' + lease_id + '\nx-ms-version:' + api_version + '\n',
    'CanonicalizedResource': '/' + storage_account_name + '/' + container_name + '\ncomp:lease\nrestype:container'
}

string_to_sign = (string_params['verb'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Encoding'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Language'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Length'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-MD5'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Content-Type'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Date'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Modified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-None-Match'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['If-Unmodified-Since'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['Range'] + '\n'
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']
                  + string_params['CanonicalizedResource'])


print (string_to_sign)


signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.HMAC(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), string_to_sign, hashlib.sha256).digest())
print (signed_string)

headers = {
    'x-ms-date': request_time,
    'x-ms-lease-action': 'release',
    'x-ms-lease-id': lease_id,
    'x-ms-version': api_version,
    'Authorization': ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string) 
}

url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + '.blob.core.windows.net/' + container_name + '?comp=lease&restype=container')

#r = requests.put(url, headers = headers, data=data)
r = requests.put(url, headers = headers)

print (r)
print(r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Annoyingly, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please update your question and include the revised code?

Comment: Already did (before I replied to your comment) - I was trying to edit my comment and didn't finish in the 5 minute edit window!

One thought - does the date in the signed string need to be the date that the lease was originally acquired?

I had a quick look at the SDK (see sample code URL below). If that's the preferred solution, I may start a new question (as I was getting different errors).

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_containers.py

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. I have found one more issue. Updated my answer with that. Regarding `does the date in the signed string need to be the date that the lease was originally acquired?`, the answer is no. It should be the date/time when the request is being made i.e. current date/time in UTC. HTH.

Comment: Made that additional change, but still no progress. Any other suggestions? I double checked all the parameters, and they are valid. Otherwise I'll have to learn how to use SDKs properly, and try that way (or get one of my Java friends to have a stab at it!).

Comment: Some progress, in that I get a new error. I had a quick play around encoding strings, but it started descending in large worm hole of utf, bytes etc. Any suggestions, as your code seemed to work for you?

Comment: Never mind - fixed it. I went back to the original sample code and copied across the utf-8 encode / decode of the signed string.  I'll update the code now for future visitors and mark your answer. Thanks again and stay safe!